# Unsetting array value in foreach loop with session?

Tags: php, session, foreach, unset

Can anyone please explain why the `unset` function do not work in the below code?

As I expected the `$_SESSION['card_nr'] = $card_nr;` stores the last looped `$card_nr` but I want it to store the card_nr the user click, thats why I need to unset (ps. I do not want to use GET).

I have tested different solutions based on web searches incl. [stack overflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=unset+array+foreach+php+session), but can not make the below work.

```
    $task_array = array_combine($task_id_unique, $task_status);
        foreach ($task_array as $card_nr => $card_status) { 
        $_SESSION['card_nr'] = $card_nr;
        ?>  
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Card nr.</th>       
            <th>Status</th>       
            </tr>
            <td><?php 
                            echo $card_nr;?></td>
            <td><?php 
                            if ($card_status == true) {
                            unset($task_array[$card_nr]);
                            echo "<a href=workcard.php>Open</a>";
                }
            else echo "Done ". $card_nr;?></td>
        </table>
<?php       }
```

Comment: what value has $card_status?

Comment: ... @sergio either 0 (false) or 1 (true).

Comment: You're looping through everything in the task array before you even check the card status condition, which is something you should be doing while in the loop. As of now, there is no connection between the two which is why it's not doing anything.

Comment: ... @sergio the loop outputs the card_status just fine.

Comment: *store the card_nr the user click, thats why I need to unset (ps. I do not want to use GET)* php is serverside so php don't notice any click from client .. to get the information (click => card_nr) you have to send a request [get | post] or use cookie or in HTML5 HTML Local Storage

Comment: ... @donald123 ok I see. I guess I could solve it by using AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my question by doing the below:

```
elseif (mysql_num_rows($results)>= 1) {
        echo "Customer: ". $customer. "<br>Active workcard:<br>";
        $task_array = array_combine($task_id_unique, $task_status);
            foreach ($task_array as $card_nr => $card_status) { 
            ?>  
                <?php 
                if ($card_status == true) { 
                    echo "<table><tr>";
                    echo "<th>Workcard nr.</th>";
                    echo "<th>Status</th></tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$card_nr."</td>";
                        echo "<td>";
                        echo "<form action='workcard_open.php' method='POST' >";
                        echo "<input type='hidden' name='card_nr' value='".$card_nr."' />";
                        echo "<input type='submit' value='Open' />";
                        echo "</td></form></table>";
                }
                ?>
```